# Error - Enable or disable IAM database authentication for the DB Cluster(Mule4 rds connector aurora)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created the dbcluster using aws-cli. and i wanted to create db instance within the created cluster using mule 4 rds connector. and when i give the values

- DBcluster name : cluster-name
- DbInstance class : db.t2.small
- DB Instance Identifier : testdbinstance
- Engine : aurora

it gives the below error:

`The requested DB Instance will be a member of a DB Cluster. Enable or disable IAM database authentication for the DB Cluster. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: e2ccfd13-f684-400f-b83f-52943bea854b)`

but while i creating i set IAM Database Authentication to false.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me:

I have both `aws rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot` and `aws rds create-db-instance` with option `--no-enable-iam-database-authentication`. 
I removed this option from  `aws rds create-db-instance` and it helped